# How to return string if no space is found

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to return everything in a string before the space:

```
select Substring('stack overflow', 1, CharIndex( ' ', 'stack overflow' ) - 1)
```

this will yield `stack`

however if we don't have a space in the data, i would like to return the entire string:

```
select Substring('stackoverflow', 1, CharIndex( ' ', 'stackoverflow' ) - 1)
```

i would like that to return `stackoverflow`

what is the correct way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Have you looked into `CASE` statements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
;WITH T(C) AS
(
SELECT 'stack overflow' UNION ALL
SELECT 'stackoverflow'
)
SELECT LEFT(C, CharIndex( ' ', C + ' ' ) - 1)
FROM T
```

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing @MartinSmith's definition:

```
;WITH T(C) AS
(
  SELECT 'stack overflow' 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'stackoverflow'
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(C, 1, COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', C)-1, -1), 255))
FROM T;
```

That said, I prefer Martin's. Both avoid checking the length or performing CASE etc., but mine assumes you know the max length of the string (here I assumed 255).

Answer (score 2):

I'm late as per usual; [here on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ef27/7)

```
CREATE TABLE The_Table 
    (
     TestString varchar(50)
    );

INSERT INTO The_Table
(TestString)
VALUES
('stack overflow'),
('stackoverflow');


select 
[myResult] = case 
                when CharIndex( ' ', TestString)> 0 then Substring(TestString, 1, CharIndex( ' ', TestString ) - 1)
                when CharIndex( ' ', TestString)= 0 then TestString
                else TestString
             end
from The_Table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;With T(C) AS
(
    Select 'Stack'
    Union All
    Select 'Stack OverFlow' 
)
Select 
    Case When CharIndex(' ', C) > 0 
        Then SUBSTRING(C, 0, CharIndex(' ', C))
    Else
        C
    End
From T
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @str varchar(100)='stack overflow'
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',@str,1) > 0 then LEFT(@str,CHARINDEX(' ',@str,1)) else @str END
```